# Перенести последовательность коммитов на другой родительский

Tags: git, git-rebase

У меня есть ветка, в ней один из коммитов является родителем для другой ветки. Я сделал в дочерней ветви несколько коммитов, потом понял, что немного поторопился и забыл сделать один необходимый в родительской. Сделал checkout родительской ветви, закоммитил нужные мне изменения. Теперь мне нужно перенести дочернюю ветвь на новый коммит, чтобы он был родительским для неё.

Попробовал сам покопаться в `git rebase -i`, но все, что смог сделать - повторить все коммиты из дочерней ветви на родительской, такой вариант мне не подходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

П.с. в удаленный репозиторий ничего пока что не отправлялось, от ваших советов ни один разработчик не пострадает.

Comment: 1. переключиться на переносимую ветку. 2. `git rebase ветка_сновым_коммитом`

Comment: @ГерманБорисов, все получилось в лучшем виде, можете оформить ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стандартный(сокращенный) синтаксис - `rebase имя_ветки` - переносит текущую ветку на указанную в параметре.

Судя по описанию, у вас сейчас текущей является родительская_ветка, значит нужно сделать следующее:

1. `git checkout дочерняя_ветка`
2. `git rebase родительская_ветка`

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно перенести часть коммитов (а похоже у Вас эта ситуация), то лучше попробовать cherry-pick  (и формально, сделать rebase ручками).

Что делать?
* перейти в дочернюю ветку и сделать `git log`. Посмотреть внимательно, какие коммиты нужны и в какой последовательности. Записать их sha хеши. Обычно 5-6 символов достаточно
* переключится в основную ветку и дальше выполняя последовательно команду `git cherry-pick <hash>`, копировать коммиты. Да, могут возникать конфликты, но их можно решить обычным способом.

Плюс такого ручного метода в полном контроле и гибкости. Можно перенести коммиты в правильном порядке, можно поправить код по ходу дела и так далее.

Comment: мне не нужно переносить часть коммитов, мне нужно перенести всю дочернюю ветку на новый коммит в родительской, причем именно целой веткой, а не повторить коммиты из дочерней ветви в родительской

Comment: ага, я кажется понял. Тогда все таки обычный rebase. Хотя и мой способ подойдет, просто нужно вначале сделать новый бранч от основной ветки и в него cherry-pick'ать.